# Adding objects to an arraylist using object elements

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to add objects to my arraylist with which I can then implement a few methods referencing an element of the object. I have two classes Balloons and MyPark (both implement other interfaces but that's irrelavant). In the balloon class there is:

```
public class Balloons implements Balloon {

private int area;
private int position;

public void Balloon(int area, int position) {
    this.area = area;
    this.position = position;
}

@Override
public int getArea() {
    return area;
 }
}
```

And in the MyPark I have created my Arraylist of balloons:

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyPark implements Park {

public Balloons balloon = new Balloons;
public ArrayList <Balloon> a = new ArrayList <Balloon>();
public int index;

@Override
public void addBalloon (int barea){
   a.add(new Balloons (barea, index));
}
}
```

But obviously this isn't the way to do it. Any suggestions? I also want to be able to eventually sort the list by area......

Comment: `public class Balloons implements Balloon { public void Balloon(...`: are you engaged in an obfuscation contest or what? Don't use the same name for everything. And respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: Noted. I have been told about that before by my professor. Bit of a nasty habit sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`public void Balloon(int area, int position)` isn't a constructor, it's a method - presumably you want it to be a constructor.

To make it a constructor, it should have the same name as your class (`Balloons`, not `Balloon`) and you should remove `void`.

```
public Balloons(int area, int position)
```

To sort the list, you basically have two options:

- Use [the `sort` method that takes a `Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29).
- Have your `Balloons` class implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and just [use the normal `sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29).

Comment: This fixed the problem I had with adding an object to the array thank you. How would I then retrieve the area of the balloon from a specified position in the array?

Comment: @user2950071 `a.get(someIndex).getArea()`.

Answer (score 2):

you can you comparator to sort your list

```
Collections.sort(SortList, new Comparator<Balloon>(){
            public int compare(Balloon b1, Balloon b2) {
                return b1.area- b2.area;
            }
        });
```